# ASP.Net MVC removing folder name in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

Good morning/Afternoon

I have a view folder with another folder and then the view name

~Views/Edit/Edit.cshtml

I would like to keep the structure like that if possible, but the problem lies within the URL

It is currently showing

```
http://localhost:63672/Edit/Edit/4
```

I would like it to show

```
http://localhost:63672/Edit/4
```

***Without the ID in the URL as well if possible, but that is a separate problem.***

How do I achieve this?

My `routeconfig` currently shows

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a controller called EditController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify a route for *Edit*.  Add this above the "Default" route currently in your `routeConfig`

**Example**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Edit", // Route name
            "Edit/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Edit", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```